# formated cout of Eigen-vectors of int with Boost format

Tags: c++, vector, boost, format, eigen

I would like to cout Eigen-vectors of int using the `boost::format` such that the numbers are right-aligned. So far I have the following code

```
int main(){ 
vector<Vector3i> foo; Vector3i bar;

bar << -1,-1,0; foo.push_back(bar);
bar <<  0, 0,0; foo.push_back(bar);

boost::format header("%3d");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    cout << header % foo[i].transpose() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
-1 -1  0
0 0 0
```

But I'm wishing to have the following output

```
-1 -1  0
 0  0  0
```

I could achieve the wanted result if I modified the format and the code inside the `for` with the following

```
boost::format header2("%2d %2d %2d");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
    cout << header2 % foo[i](0) % foo[i](1) % foo[i](2) << endl;
```

But, could someone tell me if there is a more efficient way to do this using `boost::format`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround:

```
boost::format header("%+3d"); // Add "+" when is not negative
```

This will produce the following output:

```
-1 -1 +0
+0 +0 +0
```

And also you can use `Eigen::IOFormat` to set colums delimiters like this:
(especially useful if the items has different number of digits)

```
    boost::format header("%3d");
              //(precision,flags,coeffSeparator,rowSeparator,rowPrefix,rowSuffix)
    IOFormat Fmt(3, 0, "\t", "\n", "", "");
    cout << header % foo[i].transpose().format(Fmt) << endl;
```

output:

```
-1    -1    0
0     0     0
```

Or the two tricks combined:

```
int main(){ 
vector<Vector3i> foo; Vector3i bar;

bar << -1,-1,0; foo.push_back(bar);
bar <<  0, 0,0; foo.push_back(bar);

boost::format header("%+3d");
IOFormat Fmt(3, 0, "\t", "\n", "", "");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    cout << header % foo[i].transpose().format(Fmt) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

output:

```
-1    -1    +0
+0    +0    +0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's not really what I'm looking for because I don't want to have that "+" sign. Is there a way to replace this with a space? I tried to change `("%+3d")` to `("% 3d")` but it didn't work. And `IOFormat` isn't really helping either.